# What curly braces represent when used in base of a lambda?

Tags: notation

in the following equation I'm puzzled about what exactly the curly braces represent when used in a base of a lambda. If it is a set, I haven't seen a set to be used in a base, therefore any hint would be greatly appreciated.

$$
\lambda_{\left\{ \frac{n-q}{n} \right\}}=\frac{n!\lambda^{q+1}}{\left( n-q-1 \right)!\left( \frac{1}{MTTR} \right)^q}
$$

I'm not a mathematician, I'm just fond of mathematics and stumbling upon this equation got me puzzled.

Thanks!

Comment: These things don't usually have fixed meanings, so where did you stumble upon it?

Comment: @MJD a friend of mine who works at the airport showed it to me, it calculates the availability of a civil aviation system. I understand the MTTR and the rest of the formula, but, neither I nor he understands what is the meaning of curly braces in the base of λ.